# Can't find which row is causing conversion error

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, type-conversion

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts1](
    [AccountId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

I am trying to convert nvarchar to datetime using this query:

```
select convert(datetime, expirydate) from accounts
```

I get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

The status bar says "2390 rows". I go to rows 2390, 2391 and 2392. There is nothing wrong with the data there. I even try to convert those particular rows and it works. How can I find out which row(s) is causing the conversion error?

Comment: Have you checked the rows immediately above this? You can also try copying half of the rows to a new table amending your query appropriately and if you don't get an error split the remaining rows again until you can locate the exact record. You may also want to try sorting the db by that column any strange values may leap out at you.

Comment: It would also help to know how many records are in this table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Accounts1] WHERE ISDATE(ExpiryDate) = 0
```

Here's my test code:

```
CREATE TABLE #t( 
    [ExpiryDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL 
) 

insert into #t (ExpiryDate)
select '1/1/2010'

insert into #t (ExpiryDate)
select 'foo'

insert into #t (ExpiryDate)
select '2/1/2010'

select * from #t where ISDATE(ExpiryDate) = 0
-- returns 1 row

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 1):

This table does not have a primary key. In its absence the table viewer and the query cannot be guaranteed to operate in the same order thus 2390 means different rows. As soon as a primary key is created, the row number shown when running the query will match the row number on the table view.